# Получение token vk через curl php

Tags: php, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, curl, token

Вот, собственно, код:

```html
<?php

$url = 'https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=2890984&scope=messages&response_type=token&v=5.0&display=page';
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:43.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/43.0 Iceweasel/43.0.4");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIE, 'remixrefkey=; _ym_uid=; remixlang=; _ym_isad=; emixflash=; remixscreen_depth=; remixdt=; remixseenads=; remixsid=;');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
echo curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
$out = curl_exec($curl);
echo curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
curl_close($curl);
echo $out;

?>
```

Проблема в том, что выдает ошибку:

> {"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"Security Error"}

Погуглив, я нашел, что такая ошибка может быть из-за устаревания сессии, но в браузере с теми же самыми кукисами все работает.
В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: USER_AGENT и ip одинаковый? В смысле как у браузера

Comment: Да, выполняю скрипт в том же браузере и с того же сервера.

Comment: В хроме в network попробуйте сделать "copy as curl", после чего выполните запрос в консоли. Если он выполнится успешно, то тогда уже смотрите каких заголовков не хватает в вашем php-коде.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Во первых, у тебя нету редиректа, страничку куда перенаправляется после удачного входа.

Во вторых, ты чё то мудришь с куками. Попробуй их сбрасывать CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION true.

В третьих, проверь настройки своего клиента client_id=2890984, может такого вообще не существует.

Comment: 1)Для авторизации с scope=message нельзя выставлять редирект на внешний домен.

2)Тоже самое.
3)Это официальное приложение вк.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<?php

$url = 'https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=2890984&scope=messages&response_type=token&v=5.0&display=page';
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:43.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/43.0 Iceweasel/43.0.4");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIE, 'remixrefkey=; _ym_uid=; remixlang=; _ym_isad=; emixflash=; remixscreen_depth=; remixdt=; remixseenads=; remixsid=;');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
echo curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
$out = curl_exec($curl);
echo curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
curl_close($curl);
echo $out;

?>
```

```html
<?php

$url = 'https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=2890984&scope=messages&response_type=token&v=5.0&display=page';
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:43.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/43.0 Iceweasel/43.0.4");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIE, 'remixrefkey=; _ym_uid=; remixlang=; _ym_isad=; emixflash=; remixscreen_depth=; remixdt=; remixseenads=; remixsid=;');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
echo curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
$out = curl_exec($curl);
echo curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
curl_close($curl);
echo $out;

?>
```